Why are the percentages mixed up after the webpage has been running for a day?
In this code, the month is supposed to reset "every month of the week", "every week and day", and "every day."
Based on how the code is written, when it runs for a single day, the daily percentage should be unique, while the weekly and monthly percentages should remain consistent with each other and match the daily value. However, after running the code for one day, the weekly and daily percentages are the same, but the monthly percentage is different. I’m unsure why this is happening, as the weekly and monthly percentages should stay the same until a week has passed.
Additionally, I’m wondering if this could be affected by running a Next.js app on my local machine and intermittently opening and closing my computer throughout the day. Could this be interfering with the storage of the values?
Here is the code:
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';

let holdersCount: number | null = null;
let priceData: { priceUsd: number, marketCap: string ,liquidity: string} = { priceUsd: 0, marketCap: '' ,liquidity: ''};
let priceHistory = {
  month: 0, // Use numbers
  day: 0,
  week: 0,
};

let pctChange = {
  month: '0.00', // Keep as strings for output
  day: '0.00',
  week: '0.00',
};

let isInitialFetch = true;



{/* deleted the fetch holder function for simplicity*/}

const fetchPriceData = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch('https://api.dexscreener.com/latest/dex/tokens/0x9a26F5433671751C3276a065f57e5a02D2817973');
    const data = await response.json();
    priceData = {
      priceUsd: parseFloat(data.pairs[0].priceUsd) || 0, // Ensure it's always a valid number
      marketCap: data.pairs[0].marketCap,
      liquidity: data.pairs[0].liquidity.usd 
    };

    if (isInitialFetch) {
      // Only set the initial prices after the first successful fetch
      priceHistory.month = priceData.priceUsd;
      priceHistory.day = priceData.priceUsd;
      priceHistory.week = priceData.priceUsd;
      isInitialFetch = false; // Disable the flag after setting the initial prices
      console.log('inital state done')
    }

    console.log("Old price:", priceHistory.month);
    console.log("Current price:", priceData.priceUsd);

    // Calculate the percentage change for each timeframe
    const calculatePercentChange = (oldPrice: number, newPrice: number): string => {
      if (oldPrice === 0 || isNaN(oldPrice) || isNaN(newPrice)) {
        return '0'; // Avoid invalid calculations or division by 0
      }

      const percentChange = ((newPrice - oldPrice) / oldPrice) * 100;
      return percentChange > 0 ? `+${percentChange.toFixed(2)}` : percentChange.toFixed(2);
    };

    // Only calculate percentage change if the old prices have been set and are valid
    if (priceHistory.month > 0) {
      pctChange.month = calculatePercentChange(priceHistory.month, priceData.priceUsd);
    }
    if (priceHistory.day > 0) {
      pctChange.day = calculatePercentChange(priceHistory.day, priceData.priceUsd);
    }
    if (priceHistory.week > 0) {
      pctChange.week = calculatePercentChange(priceHistory.week, priceData.priceUsd);
    }

    console.log("Price data updated:", priceData);
    console.log("Percentage change:", pctChange);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching price data:', error);
  }
};

// Fetch holders data every 8 hrs
setInterval(fetchHoldersData, 8 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

// Fetch price data every 8 hrs
setInterval(fetchPriceData, 8 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

// Reset the price history every hour, day, and week
setInterval(() => {
  priceHistory.month = priceData.priceUsd;
},31 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000); // Every month

setInterval(() => {
  priceHistory.day = priceData.priceUsd;
}, 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000); // Every day

setInterval(() => {
  priceHistory.week = priceData.priceUsd;
}, 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000); // Every week

// Initial fetch
fetchHoldersData();
fetchPriceData();

export async function GET() {
  return NextResponse.json({
    holders: holdersCount,
    price: priceData.priceUsd.toFixed(2),
    marketCap: priceData.marketCap,
    liquidity: priceData.liquidity,
    percentChanges: pctChange,
  });
}

returned values after 24 hours
The day value should differ from the week and month values, not the month value differing from the week and day after 24 hours.
I added debug statements and ran the code multiple times to try and figure it out.

I see a few points here
First of all: you are oversimplifying things, because a day (week) doesn't always have 24 (168) hours (ie when a DST switch happens), and a month certainly doesn't always have 31 days. But that's just a sidenote and most certainly not the cause of your problem. Maybe this even fits your usecase. This is your's to decide.
Second: does this happen exactly after the first 24 hours or after a longer run of your backend? Because, actually I can't see any way (in the code you show here) that the "monthly" interval's callback is executed before the "daily" or "weekly" (or even executed at all) in the first 31 days. Is this the only place where priceHistory.month is changed (aside from the initial request)?
Third: In a long run situation (ie longer than a month) one problem could be, that many your intervals are exact multiples of each other, ie after 31 days all callbacks (except the weekly) are scheduled to be executed at the same time, and it might eventually happen, that they are not executed in the order you expect, ie it could update the history.month, then fetch new prices and calculate new percentages, and only update history.day after that. This way, the mothly percentage would be calculated with a different value than the daily and weekly.
To overcome these issues I'd suggest to use a different datastructure and strategy to fetch and update your values.
Together with your data, store a timestamp, where each of the values was last updated
let priceHistory = { 
  day: 0, 
  dayupdated: 0, 
  week: 0, 
  weekupdated: 0, 
  month: 0,
  monthupdated: 0
};

let priceData = {...};
let priceUpdated = 0;

...

Then use a single (maybe even more frequent) interval and within its callback, check, what you actually need to do
setInterval(doWork, 3600000);
doWork(); //do the inital call


async function fetchPriceData() {
  const response = await fetch('https://api.dexscreener.com/latest/dex/tokens/0x9a26F5433671751C3276a065f57e5a02D2817973');
  const data = await response.json();
  priceData = {
    priceUsd: parseFloat(data.pairs[0].priceUsd) || 0, // Ensure it's always a valid number
    marketCap: data.pairs[0].marketCap,
    liquidity: data.pairs[0].liquidity.usd 
  };
}

function calcChanges() {
  if (priceHistory.month > 0) {
    pctChange.month = calculatePercentChange(priceHistory.month, priceData.priceUsd);
  }
  if (priceHistory.day > 0) {
    pctChange.day = calculatePercentChange(priceHistory.day, priceData.priceUsd);
  }
  if (priceHistory.week > 0) {
    pctChange.week = calculatePercentChange(priceHistory.week, priceData.priceUsd);
  }
}

async function doWork() {
  let now = Date.now();

  //do this every 8 hours;
  if (now - priceUpdated >= 8 * 3600000) {
    await fetchPriceData();
    priceUpdated = now;
  }

  //do this every 24 hours
  //or find a condition, that works better with DST switches
  if (now - priceHistory.dayUpdated >= 24*3600000) {
    priceHistory.day = priceData.priceUsd;
    priceHistory.dayUpdated = now;
  }

  //do this every 7 days 
  //or find a condition, that works better with DST switches
  if (now - priceHistory.weekUpdated >= 24*7*3600000) {
    priceHistory.week= priceData.priceUsd;
    priceHistory.weekUpdated = now;
  }

  //do this every 31 days
  //or find a condintion, that works with different numbers of days in month
  if (now - priceHistory.monthUpdated >= 24*7*31*3600000) {
    priceHistory.month = priceData.priceUsd;
    priceHistory.monthUpdate = now;
  }

  calcChanges();  
}

And finally, of course make sure, that your priceHistory.* is not be changed anywhere else but only in this callback. Because as mentioned above, with the code you show here, it's impossible, that the priceHistory.month is updated before at least 31 days (or 31 * 24 hours) have passed (except of course in the inital request).
This way you can be sure, that all history prices are at their correct value, before you do the calculation. And that they are only updated in your desired interval. Ie, you don't have mulitple callbacks depending on each other and depending on a certain order of execution.
